# Calling my connection method within another method

Tags: java, class, methods

How do I call my connection method and use the variables in that method for use with another method. Consider this below:

```
public final class AnApplication extends javax.swing.JFrame { 

    public AnApplication {

    // Stuff

    }
    public Connection connectDB() {

        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/car_rental";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String user = "username";
        String pass = "password";

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            if (conn == null) {
                System.out.println("Connection cannot be established");
            }       
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return conn;
    }  

}
}

public void someQuery() {
    connectDB();
    try
    {

        // Insert Statement with ? Placeholders
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.print("Connected Successfully\n");

        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableName`";


        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);

        //Execute the Prepared Statement/Query
        preparedStmt.execute();

        System.out.print("Tables inserted successfully");
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {   
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

by calling connectDB() below within my method below, I still do not have access to my variables within the someQuery method created. How am I able to create the method and make it accessible within a method when called rather than having to keep writing the connection strings over and over. Sorry if it may be a silly question, I am still new to Java and the concept of OOP.

Comment: why are your variables local to your method and not private (and final) members of your class?

Comment: `Connection conn = connectDB();`

Comment: So my variables should belong to the class directly and not the method that i created so they are accessible throughout? when i tried that, it did work fine but i wasn't sure if there was a proper and better way of doing it

Comment: I think there was a copy and paste error in your code. You have an extra curly bracket and someQuery() doesn't appear to be inside of a class. Please make sure your code was properly submitted in your question.

Comment: Sorry, just done that there and then. Even when using Connection conn =  connect(); in the someQuery method, the url, username and password variables still do not have access. do i need to change the modifier perhaps of the variables?

Comment: Why would you need access to those variables?

Comment: save me re-writing the connection, username,password and url string everytime i need them in a seperate method

Comment: And why would you need that for - other than obtaining a connection, which your `connectDB()` method already does?

Comment: ohhhhh yeah, i just realised that i don't need to keep on calling the drivermanager, only need to call it once. I am silly, sorry

Comment: Thank you for making me see sense.

Answer (score 0):

You want to reuse the same code you defined in connectDB().

```
public void someQuery() {
    try
    {

// Insert Statement with ? Placeholders
Connection conn = connectDB();
...
```

If this is a non-trivial app, you would also want to consider pooling your connection instead of closing and re-opening each time.